# Get EndPointName in NServiceBus 5

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus4, nservicebus5, nservicebus-configuration

I'm in the process of upgrading my application from NServiceBus 4 to 5.

I have a class that implements `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` and on the `Start()` method I print out the EndpointName - taking it from `NServiceBus.Configure.EndpointName`

On NServiceBus 5 it is deprecated and I want to do it correctly. How can I get the EndpointName?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ReadOnlySetting` instance, take a look at the following sample:

```
class MyClass : IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops
{
    public ReadOnlySettings Settings{ get; set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        var name = this.Settings.EndpointName();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }
}
```

Where `EndpointName()` is an extension method provided by NServiceBus in the `NServiceBus` namespace.